# 動画をクリックしなくても動くサイトの仕組みについて

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

http://www.cchan.tv/
上記のサイトは動画をクリックしなくても、動くような構造になっていますが、これはどのような技術で実現しているのでしょうか？

詳しい方、ご教示ください。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 2):

パッと見たところ、複数のjpgファイルを用意してパラパラ漫画のように擬似アニメーション表示させているようです。

使用しているライブラリは[Flipbook.js](http://nbnote.jp/library/flipbook/)(コメントがないためバージョン等の詳細は不明)だと思います。ただし、ライブラリの機能そのままの使用ではなくパラパラ漫画部分はサイト独自に定義しているようです。